# Website keeps asking to download ruby file?

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

I'm new to ruby development.  I tried to install phusion passenger and integrate it with apache on Ubuntu 14.04.

I completed step 2.3 of this page:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

But when I go to a url like `http://192.168.0.105/suburl/home.rb`, the browser downloads the rb file instead of serving it as a web page.

I'm getting lost in all the instructions. Can anyone suggest what I'm supposed to do next to get my home.rb to simply run which simply has  `puts "hello world"`?

Here's my /etc/apache/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I see that passenger.load is also in the mods-enabled directory.

Comment: you need to post configs so we can understand what you have.. its like calling a car mechanic and saying my car won't start can you fix it over the phone?

Comment: HI Mike ok I posted to config files.  Does that tell you what you need?  I'm running this off localhost at http://192.168.0.105

Comment: actually,  I shouldn'tneed anything to do with nginx right?   I made a mistake installing it.

Comment: ok I deleted the nginx config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when your browser offers you a file for download, that means that webserver doesn't recognize file as dynamic content. It's same with php/python/ruby...

For start keep it simple. Choose either Apache or Nginx to run your passenger module.

If you choose apache, enable Ubuntu Universe repositories, and then run:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

If on the other hand you choose nginx, you have to install nginx version with built-in support:

```
apt-get install ruby-passenger
```

Also, your project has to have at least 3 dirs

```
/var/www/myproject
/var/www/myproject/public
/var/www/myproject/tmp
```

and 1 file:

```
/var/www/myproject/config.ru
```

You need to set up DocumentRoot to "public" but your code starts to load from config.ru. So, this is example apache Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Take a look at 4.1 from your the document you linked.

Comment: thank you!  My issue was I didn't set up the 3 directories that you mentioned along with preparing a proper config.ru!  By the way, I have a follow up question that might be more for stack overflow that you probably know how to answer.  Will post link shortly.

Comment: actually nevermind about my follow up, I figured it out